# Do i need permit to enter to UK with my EU wife?

Tags: visas, uk, spain, eu, family

I would like to repeat my question with showing my family resident permit in Spain. I am Turkish and married with a Spanish citizen. Currently we live in Spain. I have Family Resident Card issued by Spanish authorities.

We are gonna travel to UK for 4 days with my wife and I would like to ask if i need a eea family permit even if i enter to UK with her.

Please find the screenshot of my card. It is 5 years temporal family card. At the front size say *regimen comunitario* mean that EU comunity. The back size says that *familiar ciudadano de la UE* means that family member of EU citizen.

I would like to know if i go to airport with my wife, they would let me travel and enter to UK?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Your question of yesterday was answered and linked to a full explanation. Asking it again won't change the answer. Please take a good look at those, as it provides everything you need.

Comment: Hello, i wish that you had read what was talked at other link. I asked again because they suggestes me to ask again with the screenshot of my card. Please read the last comments of the other topic before make a comment. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to repeat the same question; you can upload the image to yesterday's question by editing and replacing the image.

Comment: I was the one suggesting a new question, and to ask what is this card - namely is it article 10 one.